# Can the speed of light be measured only in a local inertial frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, observers

Whether the speed of light can only be measured at the observer's place, in his local inertial frame of reference, that is, where the measurement is made. It is about the fact that the observer (that is, his measuring devices) are in his local reference frame, but he is measuring the speed of light in some distant reference frame.

If this is possible, will there be a difference in the speed of light between a local and such a remote measurement of the speed of light, and in what examples?

Comment: The speed of light always connects two different locations. It is not possible to even talk about it without referencing two distinct points in space. I don't know what you mean by "different flow of time". Time is always that which the clocks show. The only difference in time is being observed when we look at a second clock in a different reference system.

Comment: Do not edit a question in a way that invalidates answers you have already received to the original question. I have reverted your edit. That is against the site policies

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed your comment. Unfortunately, I changed the text once more. I can revert to the original text if you think it is necessary.

Comment: @FlatterMann By the "second flow of time", I was thinking of time dilation between local and distant reference frames. As you stated, two clocks must be used. However, two clocks are two measuring devices (two observers) placed in two reference frames. Each clock is in its own local reference frame. My question is about one observer (clock).

Comment: @FlatterMann I thought about your answer some more. As you stated, two clocks are needed to measure light speed. These clocks, however, can be located in the same reference frame. It is a device (or an observer) used to measure the speed of light. However, the question is whether an observer in one reference frame can measure the speed of light in another remote reference frame.

Comment: Only one clock is needed to measure the speed of light, but we also need a ruler, and that means the speed of light is not a local quantity. It requires at least two locations and the entire connecting line between them. So while clocks are, in some sense, entirely local, rulers and derived quantities are not. Of course an observer can measure the speed of light in another reference frame. All it takes is a bunch of mirrors and a ruler in that other frame. Whatever you do, though, you always need that ruler.

Comment: @FlatterMann I agree that the measuring device must also have a ruler. However, it is questionable who we consider the observer to be. In my opinion, the observer may be a measuring device with negligible dimensions, so it can be considered to be in one frame of reference.

Comment: @FlatterMann The idea with mirrors seems to me to solve that problem. Mirrors should not be another observer measuring in their local reference frame. Due to the curvature of spacetime, i.e., the dynamic and gravitational dilation of time, the observer and the mirrors in the second frame of reference are in different conditions. This would cause the observer to measure a speed different from c. It also matches what Yukterez  said.

Comment: Physics with observers is, in general, not a good idea. It distracts from the physics. Negligible dimensions are also not "zero". They are simply physics speak for "tangent space". Unless there is no physics to first order (c is of first order in space and time), we can't go to second or higher order.

Comment: Relativity is all about different conditions. I don't know why that should be a problem? That is the core idea of it... how local physics "translates". The speed of light is the most important property that translates in a trivial fashion. Another thing are scalars in general. Whatever can be counted in one reference frame, will lead to the same count in another.

Answer (score 4):

> Spigel asked: *"Is there a possibility for that observer to measure the speed of light in some other frame of reference, where there is also a different gravity and flow of time? If there is, does the difference appear in the measurement of the speed of light?"*

Locally light always has c, but far away it can have less, see the [shapirodelayed](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Shapiro_delay.gif) velocity in the vicinity of a mass where light can even stay stationary at the horizon of a black hole, or more, see the [recessional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=938_TNP4aUs&t=5453s) velocity to which it is added in an expanding universe. The laws of special relativity only hold in the immediate spatial and temporal neighbourhood.

Comment: Since the *general relativity* tag in the question was edited out after I gave my answer and the new question now is only about *special relativity* my answer no longer fits, but it does in context of the original tag.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the text because I assumed I didn't describe the question clearly. However, your answer suits me in any case.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possibility for that observer to measure the speed of light in some other frame of reference, where there is also a different gravity and flow of time?

Of course that is possible. Simply build a device to measure the speed of light, and then have it transmit the results of the measurement to a distant observer or an observer moving relative to the device. Or even easier, make any measurement of the speed of light and simply analyze it from a different reference frame using a coordinate transform to a different frame.

Comment: In your example, there are two observers (observer + measuring device). The point is that one observer looks from his reference frame into another reference frame and thus measures the speed of light. In that example, as stated by @Yukterez, the observer can perceive speeds other than c. Unfortunately, my question was not clear enough.